# Bessel potential for $\Delta \psi + \psi = u$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\psi :\Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{R}$, and  $\psi \in \mathcal{S}'$  be the solution of the following equation:

$$\Delta \psi + \psi = u$$

Then the solution may be written as $\psi = K *u$.Where $K$ is the Bessel kernel,such that $\hat{K}(w) = \frac{1}{|w|^2 +1}$.

I need to prove that for $d\ge 2$,I have $K(x) \in L^1(\Bbb{R}^d) \cap L^p(\Bbb{R}^d)$,such that $p\in[1,\frac{n}{n-2})$ and $\nabla K \in L^1(\Bbb{R}^d) \cap L^q(\Bbb{R}^d)$ with $q\in [1,\frac{n}{n-1})$

Maybe I get the idea ,it may be helpful to integrate by part

Comment: Are you asking _why_ the inversion of $\hat{K}$ is $K$ (which seems to be just notation) or _what_ the inversion, $K$, of $\hat{K}$ is?

Comment: @mattos Oh I get it do you mean $K$ is defined to be the inversion of $\frac{1}{1+|w|^2}$ the inversion exist since this function is in $L^1$

Comment: That is what I was asking you; was your previous question asking about what the inversion of $\hat{K}$ is i.e what is the explicit function $K$ such that $$\hat{K}(w) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} K(x) e^{2 \pi i x \cdot w} dx$$ ? Or were you asking about what $K$ would mean in reference to $\hat{K}$? It now seems in your edited post that you aren't asking _either_ of those questions, only to show that $K$ and $\nabla K$ live in the respective spaces, is that right?

Comment: @mattos I think too much about it in fact,you can take $K = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{K})$ as definition of $K$ here,I previous treat $K$ as some function explictly given such that $\mathcal{F}(K) =\hat{K} $,then there may exist some question for example showing that inversion $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{K}) $ equals to the explictly given $K$

Comment: thank you $\ \ \ $